# Spring Starter: Missing Bean instead of missing value

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot with a starter. When I misconfigure the starter (missing or wrong value defined) it prints a "missing bean" error message instead of "missing value". That's pretty hard to find the bug.

My starter looks like

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "my.starter.value")
@Configuration
public class MyStarterConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyStarterExample myStarterExample(@Value("${my.starter.value}") String s) {
        return new MyStarterExample(s);
    }
```

with *spring.factories*

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=com.example.MyStarterConfiguration
```

**If the key *my.starter.value* is missing, I'd like to see an error message that says "my.stater.value is missing". Unfortunately it prints only the bean is missing. That's too unprecise. Such an error message is printed if the main application is missing a value.**

> [...] org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.MyStarterExample [...]

Can you help me to configure to print a more precise error message for my starter?

---

How to reproduce:
Download complete sources https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzbrQ3P_g0Z3U2dxbGE0enR1ZHM/view?usp=sharing

```
unzip my.problem.zip
cd my.starter/
mvn clean install
cd ../my.application/
mvn clean package
java -jar target/my.application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Now misconfigure the value for the main application *src/main/resources/application.properties*

```
my.starter.value=my.starter.value
my.app.value_=my.app.value
```

restart

```
mvn clean package
java -jar target/my.application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

there is an error message among others

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'my.app.value' in string value "${my.app.value}"

that's fine.

Now misconfigure the value for the starter *src/main/resources/application.properties*

```
my.starter.value_=my.starter.value
my.app.value=my.app.value
```

restart

```
mvn clean package
java -jar target/my.application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

there is just an error message about missing a bean

> [...] org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.MyStarterExample [...]

That's awkward. I'd like to see a missing value like for the application value.

Comment: In this case it's enough to remove the @ConditionalOnProperty to see an error message

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'my.starter.value' in string value "${my.starter.value}"

My code in production is more complex and this "fix" does not help. I need to reconsider differences between productive and this simple example...

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly use `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "my.starter.value")`, which [basically means](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html) "apply this `@Configuration` only if property `my.starter.value` exists and is not equal to `false`". So Spring boot does exactly that - when there is no `my.starter.value` property (you renamed it), it doesn't apply that configuration and `MyStarterExample` bean is not created, which leads to `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` at the point where that bean is required.

Answer (score 0):

After I removed each

```
@ConditionalOnProperty
@ConditionalOnBean
```

I get an expected error message containing the misconfigured value.

Need to look up what for I should use @ConditionOn...